# Registry access with C# and "BUILD x86" on a 64bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, iis, registry

I have an application (written in C#), which runs on an Windows Server 2008 (64bit). In this application I must check some registry keys regarding the IIS. Among others I want to access the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\WMICompatibility"**
to check if the IIS 6 compatibility mode is enabled or not. For this I use **Registry.GetValue** of **Microsoft.Win32**.

For some reasons the solution must be compiled with **x86**. The consequence is, that it is no longer possible to access **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components** but it is still possible to read key from **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp**. When compiling it with "**AnyCPU**"-flag the registry-access works fine.

So what is the reason for this behavior? Is there a solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: I don't recall the specific key names, but x86 software on Win64 resides under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow64 or similar named sub key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are falling foul of [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The best solution is to open a 64 bit view of the registry, like this:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
...
RegistryKey registryKey = 
    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).
    OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components");
object value = registryKey.GetValue(@"WMICompatibility");
```

If you want your code to work on both 32 and 64 bit machines then you'll need to code some switching between registry views.

***Note***: The capability of accessing 64 bit views from 32 bit processes was only added to the .net libraries in .net 4.  It seems that prior to that you needed to use native APIs, e.g. with P/Invoke.

Comment: He's already got the 32-bit view, he needs the 64-bit view.  Your solution requires .NET 4.  Pinvoke or a separate exe would be required for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution for the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Windows x64 has a separate node for x86 programs (not the brightest idea)

All registry keys will be under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node**

More about this issue:
[**How to view the system registry by using 64-bit versions of Windows**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097)

The program still "thinks" it's writing to the same path.

I'd suggest you fix your setup (dispatch) program to write the initial settings in the right place.

**Edit**, Some "information" from MSDN:

[Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#redirected__shared__and_reflected_keys_under_wow64)

Comment: Actually the separate node solution with redirection is a great idea. What's your better alternative?

Comment: The better alternative would be to just not have this system. It's not needed and it doesn't work properly.The registry only stores raw int and string values (all 32 bit) so why any redirection needs to occur is beyond me. Why can't they just leave the values in the normal place?

Comment: "To support the co-existence of 32-bit and 64-bit COM registration and program states..." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows