# MS Paint registry settings not working

Tags: c#, registry

Years ago, I wrote a C program that would open Microsoft Paint with a 0x0 pixel palette.  It wrote values in the registry before spawning Paint.  I have created a C# version:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace PaintZeroCanvas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
            const string subkey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Applets\\Paint\\View";
            const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "BMPWidth", 0);
            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "BMPHeight", 0);
            Registry.CurrentUser.Flush();

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\mspaint.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

The registry is modified, but Paint opens in the previously saved size.  These key names also appear in HKEY_USERS, but do not work there either.  I have administrative privileges, have FullControl access to both locations and have tried running the app with Administrative Privileges.

If I manually start Paint, change the palette size and close it, the values are written to these two locations.

I am running 64 bit Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2015 Community version, and using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: You were previously using undocumented aspects of the implementation of the Paint program. The program has been updated since then and now uses a different scheme, also undocumented, for storing user configuration. It seems there is still some use of the old registry locations, but that does not mean those are the _determining_ factor. In any case, Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, while your question is actually a question about how to use Paint, disguised as a question about programming.

Comment: If I were Paint I surely would not accept this setting as it it totally useless for my users.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge, and advance their careers."  I guess every community has their crabby neighbors...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open the 64bit Registry, like here:

[Registry access with C# and "BUILD x86" on a 64bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582020/registry-access-with-c-sharp-and-build-x86-on-a-64bit-machine)

**Note: the code below is untested!**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace PaintZeroCanvas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
            const string subkey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Applets\\Paint\\View";
            const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

            RegistryKey registryKey = 
            RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
            RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(keyName);


            registryKey.SetValue("BMPWidth", 0);
            registryKey.SetValue("BMPHeight", 0);

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\mspaint.exe");
        }
    }
}
```